# Can I have multiple FlutterPlugin in one Flutter plugin project?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm working on a Flutter plugin for internal use.

I have various domains in the plugin.

So I would like to know if we can have multiple FlutterPlugin classes in a single project and how?

Comment: yes, just create multiple `MethodChannel`s

Comment: Can you explain more a bit on how? I mean FlutterPlugin have handle method to override but it's only support one channel.

Comment: If I add another FlutterPlugin but difference class name it will not be called at the first place.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation simply use multiple `new MethodChannel` with different channel name - `new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
        .setMethodCallHandler(
          (call, result) -> {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
            // TODO
          }
        );`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update that I have found the way.

So for iOS in `FlutterPluginRegistrant.m`

You can register multiple swift FlutterPlugin, Which will allow you to have multiple method channels and classes that implement FlutterPlugin.